# Different classes, same names

Tags: intellij-idea

So I have a project with two folders structured like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TKEU.png

As you can see, the two folders have classes with the same names, but the actual class definitions are different. I need to make it so that each class only uses the other classes in its folder. How can I do this without renaming the classes? I have already tried looking in settings, but I am not sure what I should change.

Comment: What programming language would you want to do this in?

Comment: Well, don't use the classes from the other package. If a class doesn't respect that rule, fix it. If you want to make it *impossible* to use a class from outside of its package, then don't make it public.It's all about the code. Not about the IDE. If you're not using packages, then google for Java package tutorial.

Comment: You can use with the full package paths?

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

```
part1.Bigger p1B = new part1.Bigger(...);
part2.Bigger p2B = new part2.Bigger(...);
```